# How to deserialize xml when root declare namespaces?

Tags: asp.net, xml, namespaces, serialization

I have xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wnio:Dokument xmlns:wnio="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2009/03/31/119/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ... >
</wnio:Dokument>
```

I want to deserialize it to object, for example:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "wnio")]
public class Dokument
{ ... }
```

What parameter should XmlSerializer constructor has?

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Dokument), 'What here?' );
```

`XmlSerializer.Deserialize` complains that it did not expect element `http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2009/03/31/119/'>`. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wnio is just an alias.  Try this:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2009/03/31/119/")]
public class Dokument
{ ... }
```